# Cannot find an initializer for type nsstring swift

Tags: swift

I have a small question? Please help me!
Why is my code in error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type nsstring

I hope everybody help me to complete product:

```
var mangHinh:[String]! //[https://example.com/img.jpg, https://example.com/123.png, https://example.com/123_456.jpg]
var mangHinhLoaded:[String]!
var s:String = ""
var s1:String = ""
for it in mangHinh{
    var urlAnh:NSURL = NSURL(string: String(stringInterpolationSegment: it))!
    var dt:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlAnh)!
    var theFileName:String = it.lastPathComponent
    s = theFileName + "***"
    var s1 = s.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\r\n", withString: "")
    var data = NSString(contentsOfFile: s1, usedEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    mangHinhLoaded = contents.componentsSeparatedByString("\n***") as! [String]
    //I want to print mangHinhLoaded is [img.jpg, 123.png, 123_456.jpg]
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the docs? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSString`, just use `String`. Also, you don't want to use the `usedEncoding` option as you're trying to specify an encoding.

So, you should be using `init(contentsOfFile path: String, encoding enc: NSStringEncoding)`

```
var data = String(contentsOfFile: s1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah! Wain is correct. You should not use NSString in Swift.  NSString
>   is for Objective C. Just use String so that you can use the
>   initializer  for String. Take a look at the bottom portion of the
>   codes you've posted which should look like this.
>
> ```
> var data = String(contentsOfFile: s1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
> ```